# NPM not working when setting up NODE/NPM as non admin

Tags: node.js, npm, non-admin

I've been following this guide (https://theshravan.net/blog/how-to-use-node-and-npm-without-installation-or-admin-rights/) to try to use Node.js on my work computer.

I have node showing its version but not NPM after following all directions.

Current path is `C:\TOOLS\nodejs`

`npm -v` gives the response `bash: npm: command not found`

Any advice helps!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On windows, the commands 'node' and 'npm' will only work when the exe are listed under the path variable. If you can't access admin, try:

`path to node.exe` `filename`

i.e. `C:\Users\lol\path\to\node.exe index.js`

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  So I have tried C:\TOOLS\nodejs\node.exe and C:\TOOLS\nodejs\node.exe npm.cmd and  C:\TOOLS\nodejs\npm.cmd and none work.  My current path of C:\TOOLS\nodejs works fine with node, just not npm.

Comment: Inside nodejs is node.exe and npm.cmd and another folder called node_modules per the instructions in the guide